# nacl openal example doesn't work on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, openal, google-nativeclient

I'm having trouble getting openal sound working on Win7.
I've built the naclports openal-ogg example against pepper_23 on a Mac machine, and then run them in Win7 Chrome.
The result is skipping sound, and I get the following spit out to stderr:

AL lib: ppapi.c:95: buffer underrun
AL lib: ppapi.c:95: buffer underrun
...

and stdout:

Audio devices available:
    PPAPI Output
    No Output
ogg file, channels: 1, rate: 22050
    num_samples: 523734 buffer size: 1047468

The sine_synth example works fine on Win7.  The ogg file is apparently read in ok, and it sounds like it's being at least partially decoded (the sound isn't static) so perhaps it's a bug in openal-soft ?

Has anyone else seen this?  **Is anyone able to use openal-soft on Win7 successfully?**  Can anyone give me some advice about how to debug this?  I'm new to NACL.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it Chrome 25 or earlier?

Comment: One more obvious question: does it work on mac?

Comment: It's Chrome 23 on both platforms, and it works fine on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a bug in the openal-soft nacl patch.  I fixed it for myself, and eventually a project member fixed it for real in naclports:
https://code.google.com/p/naclports/issues/detail?id=57

It works now, hurray.